# Automated page visit

Tags: automated-testing, http

Bit of a weird one but I need to test a specific page on a site - Does anyone know of a web site or tool somewhere that i can provide the exact url to and it hit the site say 200 times or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools for loading websites. From [command line tools like cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/), web testing tools like the well-known Selenium to [web macro recorders like Kantu](https://kantu.io/) with record and replay features and a "Loop" button to load a website periodically.

All these tools can load a website. However, there is a difference: Kantu and Selenium use real web browser (e. g. Chrome) to load a website, whereas a command line tool like cURL does not. This might be important if you also want to run Javascript on the website.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do performance tester, selenium is not the right tool. Selenium is for functional or end-to-end tests.

For test performance there are tools like jMeter or Gatling that was built for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I've used WinTask for this.

As a routine part of my regression testing, I compare a list of pages on one site to the same pages on another site.

I wrote a quick WinTask script that takes a list or URLs from a file and compares each page in turn. It then logs any difference found.

Pretty simple stuff.